# When creating new AVD, how do I get Eclipse to display the control bar?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I created a new custom AVD to simulate the Galaxy Camera, but I am not seeing any option to have the Eclipse layout IDE add the ICS (and >) Control bar (the one with the Home, Back, Menu buttons). The other AVDs that come with the IDE display it, which makes it possible to line things up precisely in the layout preview. Without it, everything is off by ~50dp. I have set the android version to Jellybean, but beyond that am not seeing anything in the AVD configuration wizard that specifies this. What setting am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to appear in the AVD then you have to choose a suitable device from the Device option when you create the AVD, for example the Galaxy Nexus.

If you choose a non-brand device image or an image of a device that doesn't have this obviously, it won't appear.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm using the term AVD incorrectly. To my mind creating the Device is part of the process of making a custom AVD.  There is no Galaxy Camera (nor hundreds of other devices) in the stock device selector.  So, I'm creating the Galaxy Camera device and then making an AVD from that device. Also, to be extra clear, I'm not asking how to get this to show up in the emulator. I'm not using the emulator. I'm only concerned with getting it to show up in the Eclipse IDE's graphical layout tool (where you mock up the XML).

Comment: So you will have to choose the most close device suitable for you, or download an image of the device you want. How are you creating the image of this device you want?

Comment: I'm not creating an image. There is no "image" necessary (for that matter I don't even see where one would add an image).  I'm simply creating a new device to add to the list of other devices that you can preview your layout in.  This works! The only thing that's missing is that it's not displaying the control bar on the right, nor allotting space for it in the layout. The Kluge I'm using now is that I'm simply specifying the device width to be ~50pixels less than reality, but I was hoping to figure out how to get the control bar to be in there, just like it is for the Nexus devices.

Comment: just for clarity: "I'm only concerned with getting it to show up in the Eclipse IDE's graphical layout tool (where you mock up the XML)." you want to see this bar in the IDE graphical designer?

Comment: Yes, and I just figured it out. The key is to make sure to set the buttons to "software" and not check the keyboard checkbox under input. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: So you talking about the AVD and not the Graphical designer. well I'm glad you figured it out.